# 500 Error running Django, Apache2, PostGreSQL Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: python, django, postgresql, apache2

Sorry if I seem lost, but I have very little experience deploying web applications and searching online isn't helping. As the title states, I am running Ubuntu, Apache2, PostgreSQL, and Django , -- and I repeatedly get error messages, most of which are either vague and/or have no clear solutions. Plus my ignorance on the specific interactions quicksands any attempt at finding a solution, so i will be very specific.

Installations:

- apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 -- for python 3
- I can't remember if I installed django or if it automatically packaged with my PyCharm package.
- PostgreSQL - works fine.

The Application:

- It is a cloud computing platform, so it needs to receive files, store files, and render files.
- Works fine with Django's web server attached.
- has static files and needs to write to a media folder

settings.py:

```
- DEBUG = True
- WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'
-DATABASES = 
    'default': 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'example',
        'USER': 'example',
        'PASSWORD': 'example',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName FireAnts.localhost
ServerAlias www.FireAnts.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/FireAnts
<Directory /var/www/FireAnts/FireAnts>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess FireAnts python-path=/var/www/FireAnts python-home=/var/www/FireAnts/venv
WSGIProcessGroup FireAnts
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FireAnts/FireAnts/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

ERRORS, per the log

- Currently, i'm getting "No module named 'django'".
- Frequently i get "populate" is not reentrant  -- an issue which seems to have a million possible solutions.
- Target WSGI cannot be loaded as Python module.

I temporarily got another script to work by deleting all lines writing to an error.txt file -- a file that exists for both packages and generates syntax errors. For some unexplained reason, it broke again with the "No module name django" failure. Also, i moved the entire package from an outside directory to the '/var/www/' (and modified the 000-default.conf file). that shouldn't generate any issues because the virtual environment traveled with the package and the database should still connect from the outside. But I assume this generated the 500 error before by writing to a file that no longer has write permissions. Could my database be generating the error some how (by blocking the connection)? If a user uploads a package later on, it will write to the media folder temporarily. Even if it didn't write yet, could this break it? Do any more modification need to be made when moving the package to the /var/www directory? I have no clue what could be generating these errors. It must be an apache configuraton error because it works with Django's web server, and only breaks with apache2...

Sorry for the mess and lack of organization; i just have no clue where I could have messed up. - but every attempted fix just breaks it again. I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Posting the question absolutely butchered the formatting, so i apologize for that.,

Comment: are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: When you start a Django application in PyCharm, it automatically configures a virtual environment, so yes. I assume it has everything i need.

Comment: Did you activate that virtual environment when you ran the application? And can you verify that django is indeed installed in that virtual environment?

Comment: Django works perfectly fine on its own, so i assume django was included. This may be a ridiculous question, but do i have to activate the virtual environment when requested from apache? I never activate the environment, but it's probably activated with the "python3 manage.py ...." command.

Comment: also, when I got the other version to work, it was setup the same way. I fixed that one by deleting write requests to a text file.

Comment: also confirmed. Definitely has virtual environment. Previous version works  --  so it must be an update that's broken. It follows the same exact format, just different views and templates, so i'll rule out configuration. My top guesses are:

Comment: guesses: Database configuration - switched from sqllite to Postgresql  --  added static images which are not loaded in the apache2 setup but also don't exist on the home page  --  started loading other html files into current html file  --  redirect homepage directly to an application home page.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe missing out providing the WSGIDaemonProcess correctly in your default conf. Try giving as

```
WSGIDaemonProcess FireAnts python-path=/var/www/FireAnts/venv/path/to/bin/python:/var/www/FireAnts/FireAnts
```

Where replace `<path/to/>` with correct path to your venv. You have to give complete path of the python executable.

Edit the wsgi.py file of your project

/var/www/FireAnts/FireAnts/wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = '/var/www/FireAnts'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FireAnts.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: That did not work. Is the application supposed to run under www-data permissions? Standard permissions works for a previous version -- which just started working again. The only changes i made are listed above.

Comment: The error is "RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant. Last time that popped up, i was writing a file without permissions (writing a text file with in 'read only' mode. Currently my static files aren't loaded, but after the login page, they will be loaded. Also when the user uploads, it will write a file. Do i need to change permissions for any other files?

Comment: Removed the ownership part, probably not required in your case. And looking at the error, probably you have to provided necessary code to reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i figured out the answer. 
Everything was configured the correct way, but there was a missing installation with an unclear error message.
I located the file that generates the "populate() isn't reentrant" message, found the line that provides the error message, and instructed it to continue by replacing "raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")" with "self.app_configs = {}". Instead of receiving a vague, unclear answer, the error log reported a missing "psycopg2" import. I activated the venv directory and installed psycopg2. After that, it worked.